# chosen-js generated default WIDTH = 0

Tags: javascript, jquery-chosen

Using `chosen-js` with `symfony3` and `encore Webpack` I am trying to render a chosen element but the moment I load the CSS everything is broken, the generated div has `width = 0`

installed with `yarn add chosen-js --dev`

html:

```
<select id="cat-selector-lvl1"> 
   <option value='A1'>test1</option> 
   <option value='A2'>test2</option> 
   <option value='A3'>test3</option> 
   <option value='A4'>test4</option> 
</select>
```

JS (of the current page):

```
import $ from 'jquery'
import "chosen-js"
import "../css/chosen/chosen.min.css"
import "../css/chosen/chosen-sprite.png"
import "../css/chosen/chosen-sprite@2x.png"

$(document).ready( function(){
   $("#cat-selector-lvl1").chosen({disable_search_threshold: 10});
})
```

here is what I get:

[image]

the generated div is getting a width of 0; not sure why
[image]

Comment: u should add the config file for webpack

Comment: @RobertRowntree which file are you talking about please ? I import `chosen` directly inside the `JS` of my file page and I have no error loading `.chosen` method. Are you saying I need to import something else ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

specifying a width solved the issue, still think this is a bug to have default width to 0px

```
$("#cat-selector-lvl1").chosen({width: '200px'});
```